# Internationalization with Vue and TypeScript: global varibales not accessible

Tags: typescript, vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I am following this example to internationalize a Vue.js application:

https://github.com/lokalise/lokalise-tutorials

However, the application is using TypeScript, so the global variables `$i18n` and `$t` are marked as errors in Visual Studio Code.

The code compiles anyway and the application works.

So I would want to know how to get rid of those error messages, since they clutter everything, making it impossible to see real errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `shims.d.ts` file at the project root (add it if it doesn't exist) add the following properties :

```js
import { I18n } from 'vue-i18n'

declare module "*.vue" {
    import { type DefineComponent } from "vue"
    const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
    export default component
}

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
         $t: (key: string, ...params: any[]) => string;
        $i18n: I18n;
    }
}
```

The restart your IDE in order the changes take effect.